# Error in parse - Unexpected symbol in R for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, error-handling

I have a dataframe `dt` like below:

```
dt <- structure(list(Patient = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Sample-3L-AA1B", 
"Sample-4N-A93T", "Sample-4T-AA8H", "Sample-5M-AAT4", "Sample-5M-AAT6"), class = "factor"), years = c(1.3013698630137, 0.4, 1.05479452054795, 
0.134246575342466, 0.794520547945205), patient_vital_status = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), `5S_rRNA` = c(0.772491219057, 1.12342309804, 
0.283762608812, 0.882492010705, 0.805980084005), `5_8S_rRNA` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `7SK` = c(0.075067668297, 0, 0, 0.138592705037, 
0.210961230042), A1BG = c(0.0282019073358, 0.169523031145, 0.00835845927105, 
0.00515484599363, 0.0470792160901)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to apply following code on the required columns and append the each output into a list.

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
# vector with the variables to run through
genes <- colnames(dt[4:7])

datalist = data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(genes)){
  surv_rnaseq.cut <- surv_cutpoint(
    dt,
    time = "years",
    event = "patient_vital_status",
    variables = c(genes[i]))

  surv_rnaseq.cat <- surv_categorize(surv_rnaseq.cut)


  fit <- survfit(as.formula(paste0("Surv(years, patient_vital_status) ~", genes[i])),
                data = surv_rnaseq.cat)

  fr <- data.frame(surv_pvalue(fit, surv_rnaseq.cat))
  datalist <- rbind(datalist, fr)
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:37: unexpected symbol
1: Surv(years, patient_vital_status) ~5S_rRNA
                                        ^
```

I thought may be the error is due to `_` symbol in the name. I even removed that and checked but it didn't work.

Comment: Variables names can't start with a number.  Try to rename `5s_rRNA` to something else, like `rRNA_5s`

Comment: I have many names like that in my main dataframe. How to do that with any function?

Comment: You can use `dplyr::rename`.

Comment: oh no with that I have to give new names for almost 50000 old names. Is it possible?

Comment: There's a `make.names` function. It will pre-pend an "X" before names beginning with a digit.